# What is the significance of kinematic viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, viscosity

We know that [kinematic viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_and_kinematic_viscosity) is defined as ration of dynamic viscosity to the mass density of a fluid.

$\nu = \frac \mu \rho$

But I want to know the significance of that physical quantity of which unit is $\frac {m^2} s$.

Comment: It is the diffusion coefficient for momentum, like $D$ is the mass diffusion coefficient and $a=\frac{\kappa}{\rho c_p}$ is the thermal diffusion coefficient. They all have dimensions $[L^2T^{-1}]$

Comment: In the lines of @nluigi comment, check [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/163239/104402) of a similar question posted in this site.

Answer (score -3):

Let the flux density rate of momentum be represented by the tensor $\Pi$. Then, in some cases (or to a good approximation) it is the case that this is proportional to the gradient of the momentum density, say we denote it $\vec{P}$. This proportionality is the **kinematic viscosity** $\nu$.

\begin{equation}
\Pi = \nu \vec{\nabla} \vec{P}
\end{equation}

We know however, that $\vec{P}=\rho \vec{v}$ where $\vec{v}$ is the mean velocity. It must then be the case that

\begin{equation}
\Pi = \mu \vec{\nabla} \vec{v} 
\end{equation}

where $\mu=\nu\rho$ is the **dynamic viscosity**.

In summary, the kinematic viscosity describes how suscpetible momentum flow is to momentum gradients and dynamic viscosity to velocity gradients.